# Restricted folder names in Unreal

Tags: android, ios, namespaces, unreal-engine4

In Unreal 4.23, I just got this error creating an Android build of my project:

> UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): ERROR: The following files are set to be staged, but contain restricted folder names ("IOS"):

Also:

> UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): ERROR: The following files are set to be staged, but contain restricted folder names ("Apple"):

Is there a list of restricted words and folder names that obviously need to avoid. Like iOS or IOS? And visa vera for the opposition?

Time for a bit of creative respelling, anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unreal 4.25 is shedding a bit more light on its internal restrictions and possible solutions.

We have a /Windows directory in our project and UE was complaining on Xbox about it. As I didn't want to rename it to 'HolesInTheWalls' or something, I have used the white-list option and voilà, it works fine.

Here's what UE prints out during cook:

> ```
>    [Restrictions]
>    Win32
>    Win64
>    HoloLens
>    Mac
>    XboxOne
>    PS4
>    IOS
>    Android
>    HTML5
>    Linux
>    LinuxAArch64
>    AllDesktop
>    TVOS
>    Switch
>    Lumin
>    PS5
>    WinGDK
>    XboxOneGDK
>    Windows
>    Apple
>    Unix
>    Sony
>    Desktop
>    EpicInternal
>    CarefullyRedist
>    NotForLicensees
>    NoRedist
>
>    If these files are intended to be distributed in packaged builds, 
>    move the source files out of a restricted folder, or remap
>    them during staging using the following syntax in DefaultGame.ini:
>
>    [Staging]
>    +RemapDirectories=(From="Foo/NoRedist", To="Foo")
>
>    Alternatively, whitelist them using this syntax in DefaultGame.ini:
>
>    [Staging]
>    +WhitelistDirectories=MyGame/Content/Foo
> ```

Answer (score 2):

That specific error message is from Unreal Automation Tool, and digging through the engine source for that program, one finds the restricted folder names to be generated from

```
// Build a list of restricted folder names. This will comprise all other restricted platforms, plus standard restricted folder names such as NoRedist, NotForLicensees, etc...
RestrictedFolderNames.UnionWith(PlatformExports.GetPlatformFolderNames());
foreach(UnrealTargetPlatform StagePlatform in StageTargetPlatform.GetStagePlatforms())
{
    RestrictedFolderNames.ExceptWith(PlatformExports.GetIncludedFolderNames(StagePlatform));
}
RestrictedFolderNames.UnionWith(RestrictedFolder.GetNames());
RestrictedFolderNames.Remove(StageTargetPlatform.IniPlatformType.ToString());
```

The names include:

- NotForLicensees
- NoRedist
- CarefullyRedist
- EpicInternal
- PS4
- XBoxOne
- Switch
- Quail
- Any platform folder names on a platform marked as 'confidential'.
- Any platform name not currently being staged.